# 16 Port Servo Driver Won't Stop Continuous Servos Completely

Tags: python, servo, adafruit

I have a 16 port adafruit servo driver connected to my Raspberry Pi. I followed the directions (https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-servo-driver-with-raspberry-pi) to set it up. I then connected 4 continuous rotation servo motors. When I set their throttle to 1, the servos spin. However, when I set them to 0, sometimes rather than stopping they continue. When I check the value of their throttle, it's something very low, like 0.0000265.

For example, here is the code I am running (Python)

```
from adafruit_servokit import ServoKit
import time
kit = ServoKit(channels=16)

kit.continuous_servo[0].throttle = 1
kit.continuous_servo[3].throttle = 1
kit.continuous_servo[8].throttle = 1
kit.continuous_servo[13].throttle = 1

time.sleep(0)

kit.continuous_servo[0].throttle = 0
kit.continuous_servo[3].throttle = 0
kit.continuous_servo[8].throttle = 0
kit.continuous_servo[13].throttle = 0

print("Done")
print("Servo 0: {}\nServo 3: {}\nServo8: {}\nServo 13: {}".format(
        kit.continuous_servo[0].throttle,
        kit.continuous_servo[3].throttle,
        kit.continuous_servo[8].throttle,
        kit.continuous_servo[13].throttle
))
```

And this is the output (After it has set all the throttles to 0):

```
Done
Servo 0: -0.0020333468889792705
Servo 3: -0.0020333468889792705
Servo 8: -0.0020333468889792705
Servo 13: -0.0020333468889792705
```

After the throttle is set to 0, the throttle is reset to a very low number, and the Servo Motors keep turning (slowly).

Is there a way to fix this? I have enabled i2c in the `raspi-config` menu too.

Comment: what happens if you set the throttle to `-1`?

Comment: @jsotola the wheel spins backwards (in reverse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. There is a tiny screw on the bottom of the servo to calibrate it. I set the throttle of the servo to 0, then turned the screw until it came to a complete stop.

The screw can be seen in this image:
[image: Picture of screw]

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the deadband pulsewidth for the servos.  Typically it will be 1500 µs.

Use the software to send values around 1500 µs in steps of 5 µs until you find the value to stop them spinning.

The deadband pulsewidth may be different for each servo (i.e. you may need to calibrate the servos individually).